# convexity of the function f(x,y)=$\int_{0}^{x^2+y^4} e^{t^2} dt $

Tags: real-analysis

To study the convexity of this function I calculate the Hessian but is complicate to find is semi-definite positive or negative.

Comment: Let $g(x) = \int_0^x e^{t^2} dt $ for $x \ge 0$. It is convex and increasing. The function $(x,y) \mapsto x^2+y^4$ is convex. Now compose...

Comment: @copper.hat Unfortunately the composition of convex functions can be nonconvex...

Comment: @JRen: Fortunately the composition of a non decreasing convex function with a convex function is.

Comment: @JRen: A moment's thought will show how to extend $g$ for $x <0$. (This is not the first time I have seen a convex function :-)).

Comment: @copper.hat: Oh you'r right.